# How is circuit "a" simplified to circuit "b"?

Tags: circuit-analysis, norton

[image: Circuit a and b]

In circuit "a", both of those boxes are Norton equivalent circuits. My textbook says that circuit "a" can be simplified to circuit "b". How is it possible to add two current sources and parallelize both 6 Ω resistors when there's a 6 Ω resistor in between them?

As confirmed in the comments, the current source on the left in the first diagram should read \$0.5\mathrm{A}\$.

Comment: Please check the value of the current source in your left-hand box: as posted it appears to read 5A while common sense (and at least one answer) suggests it should read 0.5A.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 6 ohm resistor isn't "between" them in a way that's problematic<sup>1</sup>; it's parallel to everything else that's connected there. When you write out KCL at either the upper or lower node, you'll get a term for that resistor's current, but that term adds just like any other current entering or exiting that node.

You may convince yourself that the following circuit rearrangement produces the same KCL equation (down to ordering of terms being added up, but that doesn't matter since addition is commutative)

[image]

or even rearranged further as:

[image]

(which is, again, an equivalent circuit with the same branch constituent equations and resulting voltages and currents in each device).

However, I don't agree that 5 A + 1 A = 1.5 A. Could that say 0.5A on the left?

<sup>1</sup> Here's an example of a case where the resistor *would* be "in the way" and we couldn't do such a rearrangement (the resistor splits up the "top" of the circuit into two separate nodes with their own respective voltages):

[image]

Comment: So basically you can rearrange the circuit because the KCL equation is the same? Does this apply to every circuit with parallel components to each other? And yes, the left circuit is 0.5 A. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @SmartWallet3000 This applies for any situation where components are in parallel. As long as they really are connected to the same exact nodes/lines in a schematic, it doesn't matter where along those lines they're connected.

Comment: i see, thank you for the explanation

Comment: Just for spotting the missing "0." on the left source you would get my +1!

Comment: @winny OK, you can have a +1 too!

Answer (score 7):

Is a “0.” being drawn over by the left black rectangle?

If yes, then it makes perfect sense since it can be simplified into 1.5 A current source into a 2 Ω resistor.

Comment: Yes, its 0.5 A. Can you explain why it makes perfect sense? I have hard time understanding this.

Comment: You have two current sources in parallel which adds up linearly, 1+0.5=1.5 A. In parallel to that you have three 6 ohm resistors. Parallel two of them and you have 3 ohm in parallel with 6 ohm. Parallel those and you have a resulting 2 ohm resistor.

Comment: If you merge the load resistor, you don't preserve the load current.  So the answer given in the question is as far as reduction/simplification can go.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah yes, if i is what’s sought, then you are correct, the last step can’t be done. i would be 1/3 of 1.5 A.